# How to update StyleFrame values?

Tags: python, dataframe, styleframe

I have made a StyleFrame from some excel data. I want to update this StyleFrame values (for eg. I want to change the value in the cell corresponding  to A1 to 5). 
For eg, I have the following code where sf is the styleframe object:

```
sf[0] = 5
```

This code makes the entire column after the styleframe object to 5.
But I want to update the values in the styleframe. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: post minimal working example of you code

Answer (score 1):

Since StyleFrame wraps the values of every cell in `Container` which has `Styler` and `value` to change cells value you need to do something like this

```
sf.loc[0, 'A'].value = 3   # change the value in cell 'A1' to 3
```

**But**

The purpose of StyleFrame is to add layer of styling to DataFrame.
It is recommended to first deal with your data using DataFrame and only when your data is set, wrap it with StyleFrame and style it as you wish.

```
import pandas as pd
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [5, 6, 7]}, columns=['A', 'B'])
df.loc[0, 'A'] = 5  # change the value in cell 'A1' to 5
sf = StyleFrame(df)
# Do the styling here...
```